# Training Tensorflow only one object

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Corresponding Tensorflow documentation I trained 3 objects and get result (It can recognize  these objects). When I show other objects (not the 3 ones) it doesn't work correctly.
I want to train only one object (example: a cup) and recognize only this object. Is it possible to do via Tensorflow ?

Comment: Data Sciene 101: It's not the feamework, it's the data. If you have proper data, all DL frameworks work equally well.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't provide enough details, but as I can guess your trained the network with softmax activation and Categorical or SparseCategorical cross entropy loss. If my guess is right, such network always generates prediction to one of three classess, regardless to actual data, i.e. there is no option of "no-one".

In order to train network to recognize only one class of objects, make the only one output with only one channel and sigmoid activation. Use BinaryCrossEntropy loss to train your model for the specific object. Provide dataset that includes examples with this object and without it.